# having emulator errors when trying to run default map activity in Android studio

Tags: java, android, google-maps

// I am currently trying to run the defaul map activity provided in android //studio.  I added my API key in the xml file and run using the default AVD //device and get the following error (says my app stops working in the emulator)

// logcat:

```
    01-03 19:13:51.647 2399-2399/com.example.user.maptest I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
    01-03 19:13:51.671 2399-2399/com.example.user.maptest W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.user.maptest-2/lib/x86
    01-03 19:13:51.675 2399-2399/com.example.user.maptest I/GMPM: App measurement is starting up, version: 8487
    01-03 19:13:51.675 2399-2399/com.example.user.maptest I/GMPM: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.GMPM VERBOSE
    01-03 19:13:51.758 2399-2399/com.example.user.maptest I/zzad: Making Creator dynamically
    01-03 19:13:51.762 2399-2399/com.example.user.maptest W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86
    01-03 19:13:51.830 2399-2399/com.example.user.maptest D/ChimeraCfgMgr: Reading stored module config
    01-03 19:13:51.832 2399-2399/com.example.user.maptest D/ChimeraCfgMgr: Loading module com.google.android.gms.maps from APK /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/chimera-module-root/module-a3e4fba11e705727c59ff3116ef21fa4834b9f56/MapsModule.apk
    01-03 19:13:51.832 2399-2399/com.example.user.maptest D/ChimeraModuleLdr: Loading module APK /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/chimera-module-root/module-a3e4fba11e705727c59ff3116ef21fa4834b9f56/MapsModule.apk
    01-03 19:13:51.864 2399-2399/com.example.user.maptest D/ChimeraFileApk: Primary ABI of requesting process is x86
    01-03 19:13:51.864 2399-2399/com.example.user.maptest D/ChimeraFileApk: Classloading successful. Optimized code found.
    01-03 19:13:51.865 2399-2399/com.example.user.maptest W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/chimera-module-root/module-a3e4fba11e705727c59ff3116ef21fa4834b9f56/native-libs/x86
    01-03 19:13:51.953 2399-2399/com.example.user.maptest I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 8487000
    01-03 19:13:51.970 2399-2399/com.example.user.maptest I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 8489470
    01-03 19:13:52.122 2399-2399/com.example.user.maptest W/ContextImpl: Failed to ensure /sdcard/Android/data/com.example.user.maptest/cache: java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid mkdirs path: /storage/self/primary/Android/data/com.example.user.maptest/cache
    01-03 19:13:52.124 2399-2399/com.example.user.maptest D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    01-03 19:13:52.124 2399-2399/com.example.user.maptest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.example.user.maptest, PID: 2399
                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.maptest/com.example.user.maptest.MapsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166)
                                                                                    at com.example.user.maptest.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:20)
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                                 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
                                                                                    at com.example.user.maptest.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:20) 
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.io.File.mkdir()' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.m.ad.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.h.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.ao.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.bd.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.ev.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.z.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.y.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
                                                                                    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$zza$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$4.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1036)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1226)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1328)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2284)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:111)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:314)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(Layout
```

// AndroidManfest:

```
    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

// Gradle:
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.user.maptest"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Seems to be a problem with your permissions. Add your AndroidManifest.xml and build.gradle

Answer (score 4):

The bottomline of your problem is this line in your logcat

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.io.File.mkdir()' on a null object reference
                                                                                at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.m.ad.a(Unknown Source)
```

You need an SD card in order to run your code in `play-services:8.4.0`. Please take a look at [this](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9021&q=NullPointerException&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal) for more information about your current problem.

EDIT: This issue is already fixed. Upgrading Google Play Services to 9.0.83 will solve this issue.

Comment: I am using the virtual default nexus 5 in AVD manager, how would I go about adding an SD card

Comment: You can add SD card on emulator. Try the Advanced settings when creating the virtual device and increase the storage for SD card.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it.

Comment: I've got an empty 500MB virtual SD card in the emulator and still got this crash.

Comment: I have increased both internal storage and SD card to 4000 MB and still got the crash. Can someone provide the configuration of a virtual device where this bug does not occur?

Comment: FInally, it works for me. It's necessary to delete the existing virtual device and create a new one with large storage as suggested here: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9021

Comment: I've confirmed the above. After recreating my virtual device it decided that it had an virtual SD card again. This is good. It is unfortunate that Google Maps crashes in these cases. I've changed my program to only load my activity with Google Maps if context.getExternalCacheDir() returns non-null. Hopefully Google fixes this bug in Google Maps soon.